# How to acess a external view from the MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

This problem let my brain burst. I got two Fragments, which contain a WebView each. These two Fragments are then placed in a ViewPagerAdapter, an adapter for my ViewPager. This ViewPager is then setup with a TabLayout. In code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebViewFragment webViewFragment1 = WebViewFragment.newInstance(1);
    WebViewFragment webViewFragment2 = WebViewFragment.newInstance(2);

    WebViewFragment[] fragments = new WebViewFragment[]
            {
                    webViewFragment1,
                    webViewFragment2
            };

    String[] fragmentTitles = new String[]
            {
                    "WebView1",
                    "WebView2"
            };

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, fragmentTitles);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

This construction let me view the fragments like in e.g WhatsApp(gesture-controlled).

Nonetheless, I want to control the contents of the WebViews in the WebViewFragments in the MainActivty. But I got no idea, how to access the WebViews externally. The two webviews have IDs:

```
webView1 //and
webView2
```

When I try them to access with help of the

```
findViewById(R.id.webView1)
```

method, I get null as response.

Now, how I can access these views from the MainActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebViewFragment

```
 private WebView webView;
  public onViewCreated(....) {
       webView = view.findViewBy(R.id.webview);
       ....
  }

  public WebView getWebView() {
       return webView;
  }
```

Activity

```
    WebViewFragment webViewFragment1 = WebViewFragment.newInstance(1);
   WebView webView = webViewFragment1.getWebView();
   webView.... //WebView Stuff
```

Please make sure that the 2 Fragments are inflated and not Null.

Comment: The problem is that the onCreate loop was too fast, so the fragment had no time to inflate the WebViews.